# ruby sorting hashes inside array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have an array of hashes that I would like to sort based on the `:reference` values. But some of the elements within the array do not have a `:reference` key and therefore cannot be sorted. Is there a way to ignore this field and just sort the hash elements that contain this key?

I've tried the following approach but I'm getting an argument error

```
ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with String failed
  sort_by at org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:503



arr1 = [{:reference=> "F123",
            :name=> "test4"
          },
          {
            :reference=> "ZA4",
            :name=> "test3"
          },
          {
            :reference=> "A43",
            :name=> "test2"
          },
          {
            :name=> "test1"
          },
          {
            :name=> "homework1"
          }]

arr1 = arr1.sort_by { |hash| hash[:reference] }

puts arr1
```

The correct output should look like this :

```
=> arr1= [
        {:reference=>"A43", :name=>"test2"},
        {:reference=>"F123", :name=>"test4"},
        {:reference=>"ZA4", :name=>"test3"},
        {:name=> "test1"},
        {:name=> "homework1"}
      ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only sort on values that can be compared, so if you've got values of different types it's best to convert them to the same type first. A simple work-around is to convert to string:

```
arr1.sort_by { |hash| hash[:reference].to_s }
```

You can also assign a default:

```
arr1.sort_by { |hash| hash[:reference] || '' }
```

**Edit**: If you want the `nil` values sorted last:

```
arr1.sort_by { |hash| [ hash[:reference] ? 0 : 1, hash[:reference].to_s ] }
```

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to sort the array so that the hashes without the `:reference` keys end up at the back of the array?

Comment: I've added a method to push those to the end by adding a second element to their sorting to force them back. An array is a convenient way of doing this since it's sorted based on first element *then* second element.

Comment: You don't need `.to_s` in your last line. Strings will never be compared to `nil` and `nil <=> nil #=> 0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's a bit of paranoia that some crazy stuff like `false` might show up in there, but you're basically right that it's extraneous.

Comment: If `false` an exception is raised in any event, which is probably what you want. Note that if `false` the first element of the `sort_by` array will be `1`, so you will comparing `false.to_s #=> "false"` with `nil`, raising an exception. If you drop `to_s`, `false` will be compared with `nil`, again raising an exception (which is good). So not only does `to_s` not help, it's a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind temporary variables, you could split the array into two arrays, one containing hashes with `:reference` and the other those without:

```
with_ref, without_ref = arr1.partition { |h| h[:reference] }
```

Then sort the first one:

```
with_ref.sort_by! { |h| h[:reference] }
```

And finally concatenate both arrays:

```
arr1 = with_ref + without_ref
```